# How to design a control which would let an user to put a decimal point at an appropriate position

Tags: html, user-interface, usability

Introduce the decimal point at the correct place in the product:

```
2.5 x 9 = 225
17 x 1.17 = 1989
0.04 x 8 = 32
24 x 1.1 = 264
```

If you look at the above samples, the decimal point can occur anywhere between the numbers. What would be an intuitive way to capture user input selection here (e.g. in the second sentence, he could choose to put a dot between 1 and 9 or 9 and 8 or 8 and 9)

Comment: What language do you want to implement this?

Comment: @Nigel: it's tagged as html, seems fairly obvious that it's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can make each digit that can have a decimal point to the left of it have its own span. Then it's easy to capture an event like the user clicking the mouse (or even just hovering over) the span and adding the decimal point to the left of the span's digit.